# Multiple Forms in one page

Tags: php, forms

I have Multiple forms in one page (form is in loop)
On submit $_POST is filled with last form elements 
How can i divide this forms?

P.S forms are exactly the same because they are in the loop only 1 parameter is different

Example:

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **close** each form.

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
<?php

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your form tag with a `</form>` at the end of the loop.